# Drupal 6 - content type does not store 0 after decimal point "." in db

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-content-types

I have declared one field in content type by name "Amount" and its type as "Float"
I am trying to save 25.00000 value into amout field but it is removing decilaml point and all the zeros. 
Is there any way to store float value as it is.

```
After saving content type amount value is - 
{amount => 25}

Expected Output should be  - 
{amount => 25.0000}
```

Comment: try with 25.00001 too see if drupal didn't considered multiple zero if it's equals

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing it as number, not as the string why do you care how it is stored in DB? Do your formatting when you use the number retrieved from database:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: But when i am getting its value in api , it is returning me string "75.77".
It may be bacause i am using that vcontent type in view. is it correct ?